# PCB track width for MHz frequency

Tags: pcb-design, high-frequency

I am designing an DC to AC converter operating at 10MHz. Its a low power converter and the input current is under 2A. What PCB trace width should I use and can someone give me a guideline on how to select the PCB trace width based on the frequency.

Comment: While I appreciate the selection, you ought to be aware that it's generally a good idea to wait 24 hours or so before deciding on the answer you wish to reward. No matter how helpful my answer might be, somebody else might come along with a better one. There's really no hurry. Not that I'm complaining, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At 10 MHz, you don't need to worry about trace width/impedance unless you're using long traces and very fast rise/fall times. At 2 amps I'd worry more about voltage drops. This calculator http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/01/31/pcb-trace-width-calculator/ suggests 40 mil width if you want the trace temperature limited to 10 deg C. If you're happy with higher temps, of course, you can use a narrower trace.

If you are using very fast rise/fall times (regardless of frequency) and ringing is your problem, you'll need to use a trace impedance calculator, with the trace impedance matched to the load impedance.